# How can a passcode be entered into a web page form and POSTed in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am attempting to log into a very simple web interface. This should involve entering and submitting a passcode; I don't expect to need to keep track of cookies and there is no username.

The web page is like the following, with a simple form for POSTing the passcode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0039)http://start.ubuntu.com/wless/index.php -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Wireless Authorisation Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Wireless Access Authorisation Page</h2>

Hello<br>
<form action="http://start.ubuntu.com/wless/index.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="auth">PIN: <input type="password" name="pin" size="6"><br><input type="submit" value="Register"></form>
<h3>Terms of use</h3><p>some text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have attempted the following using urllib and urllib2:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

URL      = "http://start.ubuntu.com/wless/index.php"
data     = urllib.urlencode({"password": "verysecretpasscode"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL, data)
response.read()
```

This hasn't worked (the same page is returned and login is not successful). Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: @IsaacDj Thanks for the suggestion. Selenium seems like overkill for this task. I don't really want to blast open a full browser when really all is needed is a wee daemon in the background for this.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html
requests should be your go to module in this case

Comment: "this hasn't worked" is a totally useless description of your problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sorry, I've added more detail. When I say it hasn't worked, I mean that the same page gets returned and the login isn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form has two named input fields, you're only sending one:

```
<form action="http://start.ubuntu.com/wless/index.php" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="auth">
    PIN: <input type="password" name="pin" size="6"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

The second one is called `pin`, not `password`, so your data dict should look like this:

```
{"pin": "verysecretpasscode", "action": "auth"}
```

Comment: Boom, that was it. Thanks very much for your explanation of what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using something like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

This allows you to

```
import requests
print(requests.post(url, data={"password": "verysecretpasscode"}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've given that a try but it doesn't appear to be working. I get a response 200 and then the same web page returned and the login isn't successful.